# How to properly get rid of UNSAFE_componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, unsafe

For a React app that I inherited from another developer, one of the pages includes:

```
import { getLogUser } from "../../appRedux/actions/authAction";

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        user: null,
    };
}

UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    let user = getLogUser();
    this.setState({ user });
    // user state is used inside the render part
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    let { username } = getLogUser();
    // ... username is used inside some logic within the componentDidMount method.
```

I would like to get rid of the `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` method.

1. Can I remove the `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` part if I use `user:  getLogUser()` inside the `constructor`?
2. If that is indeed the correct way to do it, shouldn't I then also
   replace `let { username } = getLogUser();` inside
   `componentDidMount` with `let { username } = this.state.user`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start, let me explain what is `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` first

By [defination](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)

> UNSAFE_componentWillMount() is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering.

So it means `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()` will be called before `render()` (the component has not been on UI yet). This is totally opposite of `componentDidMount()` which is called after `render()`

To go deeper into why React's team wanted to make it `UNSAFE` as for a deprecated function, you can check [this RFC](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/6).

Following up on your questions

> Can I remove the UNSAFE_componentWillMount part if I use user:  getLogUser() inside the constructor?

The benefit to having your function calls in the `constructor` is similar to `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` which makes sure your data available before rendering trigger.

So I'd say yes for your case, you can do it as long as it's not an asynchronous function (like `async/await`)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        user: await getLogUser(), //YOU CANNOT DO THIS WAY
    };
}
```

This is the correct way

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        user: getLogUser(), //no asynchronous call
    };
}
```

So what if `getLogUser()` is asynchronous? `componentDidMount` comes in handy. It will be triggered after first rendering but you can wait for your data as much as you want and beyond that, it won't block your UI's interactions (or you can show a loading UI instead)

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
   const user = await getLogUser()
   setState({ user })
}

render() {
  //show loading if `user` data is not populated yet
  const { user } = this.state
  if(!user) {
     return <div>Loading</div>
  }
}
```

> If that is indeed the correct way to do it, shouldn't I then also replace let { username } = getLogUser(); inside componentDidMount with let { username } = this.state.user?

Yes, indeed. You can do it if you already populate `user` state in `constructor`, but you need to ensure your function will be executed in a small amount of time. If your function call takes too long, that will cause UI problems due to the blocked rendering.

```
//trigger before first rendering
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        user: getLogUser(), //no asynchronous call
    };
}

//trigger after first rendering
componentDidMount = () => {
    const { username } = this.state.user;
}
```

Comment: That's a great explanation! Thanks. To follow up on the last part, to account for the situation that `getLogUser()` takes too long, might that be the reason to use `let { username } = getLogUser();` inside `componentDidMount`? I mean than you don't run that risk...

Comment: Yeah, but with componentDidMount, you need to have a loading state to handle when data is not ready yet. That would be a trade-off tho. @Marty